# how to properly set up python with sublime text for python crash course

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext

Attempting to teach myself python. Bought the book Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes. Having a little trouble just getting set up. Went to the python website and got the latest version. Then headed over to the sublime text website did the same thing. I made sure python was installed properly by checking in my windows terminal which it was. After the book mentions going into the tools tab on sublime text clicking on systems, new systems then putting in this code "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"], with the curly brackets above and below and save it as python3.sublime-build in the default directory. Did all that but the problem arises when I attempt running the hello world code. I'm saving the file as hello_world.py but the response from the terminal is Python was not found; run without arguments to install from Microsoft store or disable this short cut from settings > manage app execution aliases. Sorry if this has been asked before still learning stackoverflow

I tried deleting all files and uninstalling python and sublime text i got it to work on my desktop confused on why it won't work for my laptop.

Comment: I sounds like Python wasn't added to your Windows environment PATH variable.

You can add it by going to Windows Settings, Related Settings then Advanced system settings. In that window there should be a button called Environment Variables. In the new window find PATH under system variables and add the path to the Python folder where the run executable of Python is located.

Comment: Try changing `python3` to `python` or just `py` since you are using Windows I don't think you'd have a `python3` in your PATH unless you specifically did that

Comment: Nilau when i searched on youtube that's what most videos suggested I followed the steps but it seems like that approach fixes the issue if my problem was happening with the command terminal. Python is showing its installed in the command terminal just not sublime text

Comment: Abdul I think i did what your suggesting i deleted the file from build system input the code again but saved it as python.sublime-build this time. Still not working however so i dont think i did it correctly

Comment: Abdul i took the 3 out of the code and it fixed the problem thank you so much. You too Nilau